# "Bypass" login of a php page sending username and password from asp.net

Tags: asp.net, variables, post

I'm developing an intranet (WRITTEN IN C#) which is going to gather all software applications used in my company. Some of these applications are not internal (so I can't actually see nor manage the source code).

I have to "bypass" a login page of an external application (WRITTEN IN PHP), sending username and password from asp.net (my intranet).

I don't really know HOW to manage this, IF possibile..

I only know that it's expecting a $_POST["l_username"] and a $_POST["l_passowrd"].

I've been looking for a solution for hours now..and still..nothing seems to be working. I read maaany post but there are not useful in my case.

**EDIT 1:**

```
public void sendInfo(string url, string data) 
{
    HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    req.Method = "POST";
    string Data = data;
    byte[] postBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Data);
    req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    req.ContentLength = postBytes.Length;
    Stream requestStream = req.GetRequestStream();
    requestStream.Write(postBytes, 0, postBytes.Length);
    requestStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
    Stream resStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    var sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    string responseText = sr.ReadToEnd();

    req.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
}
```

This is the code I've been trying to use when I click on the link (I'm using a LinkButton)..but it is not redirecting me to the page. It's supposed to redirect, logging in using the parameters I give in Data and show me the main page of the external application..any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

**EDIT 2:**

I found a code which seems to be working, finally!

You can find it ->[HERE](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37539/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET)<-.

I tried it using a simple Web Form (with a LinkButton) and a class, it works perfectly.

My problem now is that my intranet uses a MasterPage, and when I'm calling the method from a Content Page..nothing happens.

What can I do to have this code working on a Content Page?

Comment: Could you use CURL to login then do what every necessary work you need to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I used this ->[code here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37539/Redirect-and-POST-in-ASP-NET)<- and it worked just fine.

Couldn't understand why it won't work using master and content pages, but I managed without them.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the POST method for WebRequest (more details in this SO answer: [curl Request with ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16619065/curl-request-with-asp-net) )

Answer (score 0):

You should build a Request with [the ASP.net WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9(v=vs.110).aspx). You know which data to send, so that shouldn't be a problem!

Comment: I tried it but it's not redirecting me to the main page..I'm supposed to click on a link, doing "all this login bypassing stuff", and actually get to the main page..already logged. I'm sorry..I'm completely new to this..

Comment: You should get something like a cookie from the WebRequest Response. But i think ->[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8891386/in-asp-net-how-can-i-login-from-a-remote-html-page-into-another-aspx-page-with)<- could be somethinng for you. It does not make any difference in which language the other website is written, by the way.